# C: Warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]

Tags: c, pointers

A bit fairly new to C, and was confused about this warning I'm receiving in this function:

```
void fillPrioritiesArr(int ** priorities, int arrSize) { 
  int currIdx = 0;
  while(currIdx < arrSize){
    priorities[currIdx]=malloc(sizeof(int));
    priorities[currIdx] = (int) rand() % 10;
    currIdx++;
  }
}
```

Specifically this line:

```
priorities[currIdx] = (int) rand() % 10;
```

Is it due because one is a pointer variable and the other is an int? Or is my understanding of this completely wrong?

Comment: Your understanding is correct,

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
void fillPrioritiesArr(int ** priorities, int arrSize) { 
  int currIdx = 0;
  while(currIdx < arrSize){
    priorities[currIdx]=malloc(sizeof(int));
    *priorities[currIdx] = (int) rand() % 10;
    currIdx++;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the line

```
priorities[currIdx] = (int) rand() % 10;
```

you are trying to assign an `int` on the right-hand-side (rhs) of the the `=` to something that has type `int*` on the left-hand-side (lhs). The lhs is a variable that holds a pointer to a storage location where you can store an `int`. So, in order to write to that location, you first must dereference the pointer variable with `*priorities[currIdx]`. This tells the compiler: "Don't write to the variable itself but look up the location where it points and write there."

This is similar to what you do when you say `priorities[currIdx]` in the first place. The variable `priorities` is an `int**`. That's a pointer to a pointer to an `int`. You don't want to override the variable itself but you want to write the location it points to (which has type `int*`) with a fresh pointer. In that case you dereference saying `priorities[currIdx]` which is equivalent to `*(priorities + currIdx)`.

---

However, allocating an extra `int` for each slot of the array is not only unneccessary and cumbersome, it also makes your code much slower. You can have an array of `int`s directly, by simply passing `int* priorities`. *Then* you can just drop the `malloc` line alltogether and write to the array as you do in your question originally. That is, without dereferencing:

```
priorities[currIdx] = (int) rand() % 10;
```

because `priorities[currIdx]` will then have type `int`.

Answer (score -1):

`priorities [currIdx]` is of integer pointer type. You can't assign int to address.

Do this:

```
int temp = (int) rand()%10;

memcpy(priorities [currIdx], &temp, sizeof(int);
```

Comment: Why not just  `*priorities[currIdx] = (int) rand() % 10`?

Comment: I tried both `*priorities[currIdx] = (int) rand() % 10` and `priorities[currIdx] += (int) rand() % 10` , but both doens't give the values 0-10 instead a way larger number.

Comment: @Hyun how are you calling `fillPrioritiesArr`? Is it `priorities` is pointing to valid memory?

Comment: @kiranBiradar
`int ** priorities = malloc(sizeof(int *) * ARR_SIZE);` 
`fillPrioritiesArr(priorities, ARR_SIZE);`

Comment: @kiranBiradar Ah, wow I feel like an idiot. Fixed it now (: Was outputting `priorities[idx]` which should've been `*priorities[idx]`